# UISearch bar case insensitive?

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar, case-sensitive

In a table view I have set a UISearchBar, set the delegate, and add the protocol.

When user tap a word everything is okay except that the search of "tennis" is different from "Tennis".

How can I make the search bar a case-insensitive UISearchBar?  Here is my code where I think evrything happens:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
 [tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search
 if([searchText isEqualToString:@""]||searchText==nil){
  [myTableView reloadData];
  return;
 }
 NSInteger counter = 0;
 for(NSString *name in dataSource)
 {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
  NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText];
  if(r.location != NSNotFound)
   [tableData addObject:name];
  counter++;
  [pool release];
 }
 [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to do this is probably

```
 NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [DetailSearchArray removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search

    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""]){
        [table reloadData];
        return;
    }

    NSInteger counter = 0;
    NSArray *result = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[resultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

    for (NSString *name in  resultArray  ) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        //NSRange r=[name rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if(r.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.
            {
                [DetailSearchArray addObject:name]; 
            }
        }

        }
        counter++;
        [pool release];
    }

    [table reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do the comparison, try doing it with the lowercase version.

```
NSRange r = [[name lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];
```

Just to clarify, this will not change any of the values, just return a lowercase version of the original, that you then use to do the comparison with,

Answer (score 0):

Theres some 'lowercaseString' function, don't know where I came across this seeing as I have nothing to do with iPhones, I'm sure if you google it you'll find something.