# Case insensitive SearchBar Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, searchbar

I'm developing an app in Xcode in Objective-C. The app has a TableView with restaurants. My problem is that when I use the SearchBar the filter is case sensitive and I want to get a case insensitive search.
I know I have to change my `searchBar textDidChange` method, and I looking for help but I don't know how to change it in my case. Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

This is my `searchBar textDidChange` method:

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        //Set our boolean flag
        isFiltered = NO;
    } else {
        //Set our boolean flag
        isFiltered = YES;
    }
    //Alloc and init our filteredData
    filteredRest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Restaurant *item in originData) {
        if ([item.title containsString:searchText]) {
            [filteredRest addObject:item];
        }
    }

    //Reload our table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UISearch bar case insensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458636/uisearch-bar-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line

```
if ([item.title containsString:searchText]) {
    [filteredRest addObject:item];
}
```

With this

```
if ([[item.title lowercaseString]containsString:[searchText lowercaseString]]) {
    [filteredRest addObject:item];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should update the code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        //Set our boolean flag
        isFiltered = NO;
    } else {
        //Set our boolean flag
        isFiltered = YES;
    }
    //Alloc and init our filteredData
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
    filteredRest = [originData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]

    //Reload our table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more best solution.

```
if (!([item.title rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound))
    {
       [filteredRest addObject:item];
    }
```